# Moving and upgrading a whole SQL server instance (2008->2008R2) from a physical server to virtual server (2003->2008)

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am not a DBA/server admin, and unfortunately we don't really have any currently. My organization wants to move a SQL server 2008 instance running on Windows Server 2003 (physical) over to 2008R2 running on Windows Server 2008 (Virtual).

I am wondering if there are any tools that would make this process as painless as possible? We want to move over everything icluding logins, SQL agent jobs, etc if possible. It looks like we could use the built-in Copy Database Wizard to move the databases themselves, but how about the other server objects?

Comment: Is it just performing too quickly for you? there's got to be a reason why you'd want to make your first VM a DB server right? The first rule of virtualising is 'don't virtualise DB boxes without a lot of thought'.

Comment: We have other virtual servers running 2008 (web servers mostly), so my understanding is that it's pretty easy for them to set a new one up. If it will cause performance issues I could certainly make the case that we need a dedicated physical box. Again, I am not a DBA/server guy so forgive my lack of knowledge in the area.

Comment: Seriously - hire a consultant for this. This site is meant for admins, which you admit that you're not. You're asking for a couple hundred bucks worth of free work. If you said : "I'm learning on the job, and here's what I've tried, and I got stuck here" that would be entirely different and in-line with the intent of this site. You're asking for someone to plan this project for you, and/or this is a shopping question for tools.

Comment: I don't need anything like that, all I really wanted to know is if there is a tool that would just help a little bit. A name or a link. If we need to script out what we can and do the rest manually then we will. I just figured if there were any helpful tools out there, this would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done this myself but I see no reason why it can't work, if you have access to integration services have a look at the following links.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2064/transfer-database-task-and-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-in-ssis/

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2081/transfer-sql-server-jobs-task-and-transfer-sql-server-logins-task-in-ssis/

The second link was the top result of the [google search for "migrate SQL jobs and logins"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=migrate+SQL+jobs+and+logins+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a), there are quite a few results so you may want to read through them and see if there are any more results that would suit you better

Comment: That looks like it could work. I also found this http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1792/upgrading-to-sql-server-2008-using-copy-database-wizard/ from that link. It appears the wizard handles more than I initially thought.